# Elasticsearch, making many requests and having to sort every request - is there a faster way?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a program that grabs millions of records from the elasticsearch service, I am using the search after query to get more than 10,000 records and sorting by timestamp.

- this is my query in sudo code
  `get /_search { search_after : whatever the last record was in last pull, sort: by timestamp }`

It seems that every request i send, it has to sort again and again which takes considerable time.

Is there a way to sort once and then all the records remain in the same position so i do not have to sort again and again. I have thought of PIT possibly but not sure if this holds the same sorting order.

I have tried just the sort after but i need something faster.

Comment: You can get records until you have the whole data set, then sort. You can sort each part and merge (https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge). You can sort each part, add them together, then sort again (timsort takes advantage of already-sorted data https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts). Since these all fundamentally do the same thing you'll have to benchmark to see which option is best for your case.

Comment: You might be able to improve over n log n sorting with some domain knowledge to bucket sort on the timestamps. Obviously that won't work in the general case, but you didn't really say anything about your data, so maybe.

Comment: Can you re index your data ? If so you might be interested in the [index sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-index-sorting.html) which should considerably help